# How to center in div without text-align?

Tags: html, css

How to center squares in the `wrapper` without using `text-align:center`? 
I need this because it also centers all text in squares, but I don't need this.

**HTML** :

```
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="squares">
            <div class="square">lol</div>
            <div class="square">lol</div>
            <div class="square">lol</div>
            <div class="square">lol</div>
            <div class="square">lol</div>
            <div class="square">lol</div>
            <div class="square">lol</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**:

```
html, body{
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    line-height: 18px;
}

#wrapper{
    width: 960px;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.square {
    width:251px;
    height:207px;   
    border: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    margin: 10px;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    background-color:#fff;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: why not just add `text-align: left` to `.square`?

Comment: @JanDvorak he needs margin

Comment: He can set margin to squares instead of square...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
#wrapper{
    ...
    text-align: center;
}
.square {
    ...
    text-align: left;
}
```

---- Another way (I don't recommed!)

How to find 52px: (width of div - (#of squares * width of one square))/ #of squares+1 -> 
(960-(250*3))/4

```
#wrapper{ 
... 
padding-left:52px; 
} 
.square {
...
margin: 10px 52px 10px 0;
}
```

Comment: Your alternate solution only works if the elements are guaranteed to have a specific width and will be a pain in the ass to go back and change should the widths change in the future.  Changing the alignment is the simplest solution.

Comment: Yes I know you're right @cimmanon. I gave the alternative if Kirix insists of not using text-align:center.

Answer (score 9):

You can try:

```
.squares {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it is text inside the squares you are styling you could put an `H` or `P` tag around the text and then `text-align: left;` them.